# Trying to reset NativeScript Preview

Tags: android, nativescript, preview

I'm trying to reset NativeScript Preview but after press and holding lunch icon, android system just let me move icon instead open menu. So, doing with original instruction: "Resetting the Preview app" from: https://preview.nativescript.org/#faq . Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the problem is related to version of my Android - v.6.
This feature working in Android v.11.(I meant the press and hold app icon to open it's menu)
My old Galaxy S5 is unable to upgrade to higher version. So, I consider change to LineageOS which is quite time consuming and a bit risky process or buying new mobile with newer version o android system.
Still question is on which version started with this option.